# UINavigationBar background image applied twice in iOS 7.1 ONLY

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, background-image, ios7.1

I was testing my app on iOS 7.1 using Xcode 5.1 . I can see UINavigationBar background image applied twice in iOS 7.1 with non-retina iPad device ONLY . If I run the app on iPad retina device , it shows  image correctly. Here is the screenshot in **Non-retina device**

[image]

Here is screenshot from **RETINA device**

[image]

Navigation bar background image is **transparent** . Here is my code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [self configUI];

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }

    -(void)configUI
    {
        if (IS_IPAD)
            self.homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController~iPad" bundle:nil];
        else
            self.homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController~iPhone" bundle:nil];

        self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.homeVC];

        UIImage *bg;

        if(IS_IPAD)
            bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait_screen_bg~ipad"];
        else
            bg = [UIImage imageNamed:IS_IPHONE_5?@"screen_bg_i5":@"screen_bg"];

        UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
        [self.navController.view insertSubview:bgImageView atIndex:0];
        [self.navController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.navController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        if(IS_IPAD)
        {
            // Nav bar image with height = 44
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_portrait_ios6~ipad.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_landscape_ios6~ipad.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];

        }
        else
        {
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_bar_bg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }

        UIFont *titleFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Book" size:20];
        NSDictionary *attrib = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                titleFont,              NSFontAttributeName,
                                [UIColor whiteColor],   NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                nil];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attrib];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    }
```

I checked with designer , there is no issue in image. Both retina as well as non-retina images are same except dimensions gets doubled.

```
non-retina image size = 768 x 44
retina image size  = 1536 x 88
```

**IMP Note: Using above code , app works perfectly & showing correct image in non-retina devices with iOS < 7.1 This issue is in iOS 7.1 ONLY**

Comment: Just a head up, this piece of code: `if (IS_IPAD)
            self.homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController~iPad" bundle:nil];
        else
            self.homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController~iPhone" bundle:nil];` is exactly the same as : `self.homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];` but you should rename `~iPad` to `~ipad` and `~iPhone` to `~iphone`. This is also valid for images.

Comment: Thanks for catching this point. I am using it correctly in my application. This code is from sample app. I will fix it & take care of it now onwards :)

Comment: I have reported this bug to Apple , bug id = 16470576. I received reply from them as below 
`Engineering has determined that your bug report is a duplicate of another issue and will be closed. Duplicate of 16377955 (Open) 
`